# how to make cygwin build program in windows use windows path

Tags: cygwin

I built and installed a program with cygwin in windows, but the program can not find windows style paths and must use /cygdrive 
I just want to know how to spare this burden

The problem is this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>protoc -If:
f: warning: directory does not exist.
Missing input file.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>protoc -I/cygdrive/f
Missing input file.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem with windows stuff, it always uses spaces in paths. Two solutions:

1st. Open your cygwin (black one) terminal and type (I suppose you will be in your home directory):

```
cp /etc/dev/etc/skel/.bash* .
```

this will copy all the bash files you need to your current directory to "handle" your cygwin system. To know where you are in your cygwin (ie. the path to your current directory) type "pwd" (without the quotes) and press Enter (or Return for some people).

2nd. Open the .bashrc file already copied and type (I use "vi" editor for this but you can use "pico" which is a bit easier):

```
alias C="C:\Documents\ and\ Settings\Administrator"
```

save the .bashrc ("Ctrl+X" in pico I think, and :wq in "vi") and close the terminal. After restarting this console, typing "C" and pressing enter will send you automatically to "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator"

To know which alias you have, just type "alias" in your terminal and all your alias will show up.

HTH,

Comment: i really appreciate your help,but i don't think that you understand what i nead. i want to know how can i make cygwin building program work like a windows program. now i know that it is difficult for me,so i decide to use mingw